# Does JpaRepository optimize @Query(SELECT ... WHERE...) request?

Tags: hibernate, optimization

In my jpaRepository I have a custom method annotated with parametrized `@Query(SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE ..)`.

If all the parameters are null then the query is fully equivalent to simple SELECT .. FROM .. without any WHERE. Therefore, the method becomes equivalent to `findAll()` method.

The question is: Do we need the method `findAll()` in our repository to get all records or we can use our custom method with null parameters for this without a performance loss?

The code is:

```
public interface EmployeeJpaRepository extends EmployeeRepository, JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {


    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE (:firstName IS NULL OR e.firstName = :firstName) " +
           "AND (:lastName IS NULL OR e.lastName = :lastName)" +
           "AND (:firstName IS NOT NULL OR :firstNameLike IS NULL OR e.firstName LIKE %:firstNameLike%)" +
           "AND (:lastName IS NOT NULL OR :lastNameLike IS NULL OR e.lastName LIKE %:lastNameLike%)")
    List<Employee> findAllFilteredByFirstNameAndLastName(
            @Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName,
            @Param("firstNameLike") String firstNameLike, @Param("lastNameLike") String lastNameLike);

    List<Employee> findAll(); // Do we need this method if we can use findAllFilteredByFirstNameAndLastName(null, null, null, null) instead?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `findAll` is better because each condition needs to be evaluated, even if all parameters are null.

From a SQL point of view, try to evaluate the performance of

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (null IS NULL OR field = null) AND ...
```